# Grouping items in list where the first item is the same

Tags: python

how to group items on list based on the first item? for example:

```
list= [{'main': 0328, 'a':1},{'main': 0328, 'b': 2},{'main': 0486, 'a': 5},{'main': 0486, 'b': 6}]
```

will be transformed to:

```
list [{'main: 0328','a':1, 'b':2}, {'main': 0486, 'a':5, 'b': 6}]
```

or this is better:

```
list [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b': 6}]
```

Comment: By writing some code, I guess.

Comment: Please share how are you trying to approach the solution. Some python code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Demo:**

```
from itertools import groupby
l= [{'main': 328, 'a':1},{'main': 328, 'b': 2},{'main': 486, 'a': 5},{'main': 486, 'b': 6}]
res = []
for key, group in groupby(l, lambda x: x["main"]):
    d = {}
    for i in group:
        del i['main']
        d.update(i)
    res.append(d)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried ordered and default dict, but this is the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, short, easily readable and elegant IMHO:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList= [{'main': 328, 'a':1},{'main': 328, 'b': 2},{'main': 486, 'a': 5},{'main': 486, 'b': 6}]

myDict = defaultdict(dict)

for d in myList:
    myDict[d.pop('main')].update(d)

print(myDict)            # {328: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 486: {'a': 5, 'b': 6}}
print(myDict.values())   # [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and simpler answer :)

Comment: You're welcome, sir ! Please consider selecting the best answer and up-voting useful ones.